# Flash Bitmap quality issue with iPhone

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, bitmap, flash-cs6

So I am using AIR to make a mobile version of a flash game. All the game graphics is transformed into Bitmaps, with the purpose of having high Frame Rates. Everything is fine, except for the iOS version of the game, specifically the iPhone version. On every iPhone I tested, the bitmaps have bad quality. If I play the game on any android device the quality of the game is perfect, same goes if I play on iPad.

I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: What are your SWF dimensions and bitmap dimensions? IIRC IPhones nowadays have a very hi-res screen, so when you app is played there, interpolation (bilinear, most likely) occurs to fill up pixels that don't match bitmap coordicates perfectly.

Comment: did you set <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution> to the app-description.xml?

Comment: thank, i set it high and it worked, my man u deserve a beer :D